# bootsnav.js:559 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'offset' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new in js, any ideas what am missing here,thanks

```
 var fixSpy = function() {
                var data = $body.data('bs.scrollspy');
                if (data) {
                    offset = getNav.outerHeight();
                    data.options.offset = offset;
                    $body.data('bs.scrollspy', data);
                    $body.scrollspy('refresh');
                }
            }
```

Comment: try console logging offset. it must be undefined. you are not getting it from getNav

Comment: @AnasM.I console.log(offset); is actually coming through with a value